# Linkedin appication permission for client credentials flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, client, linkedin-api, credentials

I created a Linkedin application and now need to have this application granted permission to use the Clent Credentials Flow. On the Linkedin site (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow) it is stated that you have to contact Linkendin for this. I tried contacting the Linkedin help site but they could not help me, actually suggesting to ask the question here on stackoverflow.com. So, does anyone know who to contact at Linkedin to get my application granted permission to use the Client Credentials Flow? Thank you all for your help,
Regards, Dennis

Comment: Maybe you want to implement [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) flow?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did have a look at that flow but it is not wat we want. Using the client credentials flow would be the better option for us. We need the solution for showing the linkedin posts of a client on the intranet of that client.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for LinkedIn, not StackOverflow

Comment: For me it is ok to close the question. I do agree that the question is for LinkedIn but unfortunately I could not find anyone to give me a good answer. LinkedIn is not really willing to help me out.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this? Did Linkedin help you on that? I have the same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

All two-legged flows would require partnership/extended access (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) for which the use cases are pretty narrow and deliberate as indicated there. You would apply to be a partner effectively, but you should be sure your use case falls into those categories of value before requesting partnership. Otherwise one would develop three-legged flows that work with our public/open/self-serve [APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/).